# SBT multi-project build classpath problems

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have a SBT project I'm trying to separate into a multi-project build.

For some reason, there are a few tests I can't get to work when running the tests from the root build.

These tests use Akka, and it looks something is wrong with the class path - the config is not loaded properly and I get this error:

```
[error]  com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka' (SimpleConfig.java:152)
```

The dependency is configured for the sub-project, and works fine when I run the tests from within the project itself, and not from the root build.

Does someone know how can I get this to work?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does your root project aggregate on your sub modules?

Comment: Yes, and all tests run fine, except the ones that try to load the configuration at runtime. They work when I execute `sbt test` from the submodule, but not from the root

Answer (score 1):

Just been having this problem myself, we managed to solve it by enabling [forking](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html) in the project:

`ThisBuild / fork := true`